# Aliasing a function in Perl

Tags: perl, function, alias

In Perl, if I want `foo()` to do exactly what `bar()` does, I can do this:

```
sub foo {return bar(@_);}
```

Is there a better way? Something closer to Ruby's "alias" operator?

Comment: Do you want `foo()` to continue to do the same thing as `bar()` no matter what, i.e. even if `bar()` gets redefined?

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered. Both these functions are in a library, so I don't plan to redefine either. "*foo = \&bar;" works fine for me!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

<strike>The</strike> A better way, employed by `Exporter` and similar modules, is to edit your symbol table:

```
*foo = \&bar;
```

(edited because this is Perl we are talking about)

Comment: while globs are the entries of symbol tables, they aren't the same thing at all; you can make that kind of assignment to a glob whether or not it is in a symbol table.

Comment: @ysth not sure I get your point, or how it applies to my answer but not to yours. Sure, globs have uses other than accessing the symbol table (filehandles, for example). But assigning to a glob is the canonical way of editing the symbol table (and the only way I'm comfortable with).

Comment: I guess I don't consider that to be accessing the symbol table; it's just changing a glob, one that happens to be a value in the symbol table.   `$::{foo} = *bar` is accessing the symbol table.  *foo= seems more similar $foo= than to using %::, etc.

Answer (score 16):

There is another way to do it:

```
sub foo {goto &bar}
```

This preserves the equivalence between `foo` and `bar` even if `bar` is subsequently redefined.

Here is a detailed demo:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub bar {
    print "This is the original bar().\n";
}

*bar_copy = \&bar;

sub bar_link {
    goto &bar;
}

print "Executing bar_copy:\n";
bar_copy();
print "Executing bar_link:\n";
bar_link();

*bar = sub {print "This is bar(), redefined.\n"};

print "Executing bar_copy after redefinition:\n";
bar_copy();
print "Executing bar_link after redefinition:\n";
bar_link();
```

which prints

```
Executing bar_copy:
This is the original bar().
Executing bar_link:
This is the original bar().
Subroutine main::bar redefined at C:\scripts\temp.pl line 19.
Executing bar_copy after redefinition:
This is the original bar().
Executing bar_link after redefinition:
This is bar(), redefined.
```

Answer (score 12):

```
*foo = \&bar;
```

Assigning a reference to a glob replaces that portion of the glob with the thingy referred to.  So this makes &foo exactly the same as &bar.

```
*foo = *bar;  # or \*bar
```

This also works, but also aliases the scalar, array, hash, filehandle, and format between foo and bar.

Answer (score 6):

Courtesy [Perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=713724):

```
sub bar { print( "Hello World\n" ); }

BEGIN { *foo = \&bar; }

foo();
bar();
```

Comment: Is the BEGIN block required here?

Comment: In this particular example, the parser can understand that `foo()` is a subroutine call without the BEGIN block. In more complex scenarios, such as `foo 1, 2, 3` or `sub bar(&@) {...} *foo = \&bar; foo {...} 1, 2, 3`, to help the parser to differentiate subroutine call, BEGIN block should be used, which is executed as soon as it is parsed (see [here](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.18.4/perlmod#BEGIN%2C-UNITCHECK%2C-CHECK%2C-INIT-and-END)).